# Upgrading the status of a base class to a brand new instance of an inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management

I want to take an instance of `BaseClass` which was creating using the BaseClass constructor and upgrade it to an instance of `Inherited`. I know that the Inherited class needs a separate block of memory allocated for it and that the original BaseClass instance should be freed.

This is a (seemingly) working example of this.

```
class BaseClass{
public:
    BaseClass(int mem1, int mem2){
        this->mem1 = mem1;
        this->mem2 = mem2;
    }

    BaseClass(BaseClass* base){
        this->mem1 = base->mem1;
        this->mem2 = base->mem2;
    }

    virtual ~BaseClass(){
        printf("Deconstruct Base\n");
    }

private:
    int mem1;
    int mem2;
};

class Inherited: public BaseClass{
public:
    Inherited(int mem1, int mem2, int mem3): BaseClass(mem1, mem2){
        this->mem3 = mem3;
    }

    Inherited(BaseClass* base, int mem3): BaseClass(base){
        this->mem3 = mem3;
        free(base); // this doesn't print 'Deconstruct Base'
    }

    ~Inherited(){
        printf("Deconstruct Inherited\n");
    }

    int mem3;
};

int main(){
    BaseClass* p = new BaseClass(1, 2);
    p = new Inherited(p, 3);

    // this prints 'Deconstruct Inherited' then 'Deconstruct Base'
    delete p; 
}
```

So in the constructor for my Inherited class, I use `free` to deallocate the memory of the original instance of `BaseClass`.

The goal of this is that if `BaseClass` has a pointer to a large block of dynamically allocated memory, I would like the Inherited class to pick up that pointer instead of letting BaseClass deallocate it.

**My questions are:**

Would this leak memory for any reason?

Is there a cleaner way to do this? (for example: would calling `operator delete` be a better option than `free`? Or is there a better solution entirely?)

Comment: Calling `free` instead of `delete` is undefined behaviour, but what you should use are smart pointers.

Comment: **Every** `new` needs a `delete`.

Comment: @Quentin Good information on the `free` call, but I don't think smart pointers are what I'm looking for. I modified the question to detail that I don't want the deconstructor called for `BaseClass` when it is upgraded.

Comment: That kind of code does not make sense. You have a lot of undefined behaviors, inefficient code, memory leaks, non conventional "copy" constructor, useless code and hard to read code. If you want the derived class, the create it correctly from the start. **Reading a book or two would surely be a good idea**

Comment: Your code in main should be: `Inherited obj(1, 2, 3);`. No need for pointer, dynamic allocation and trying to update the type of an object

Comment: @Phil1970 well since I AM trying to upgrade the type of the object and the question is about upgrading the type of an object, I can't say your comments are extra helpful.

Comment: The most important questions here is why are you using raw pointers and `new`/`delete`? There is no thing as `upgrading` an object. What you can do is what you already tried, construct an `Inherited` from a `BaseClass`. Trying to mix in memory clean-up in the constructor looks absolutely terrible. Use smart pointers.

Comment: There are a lot of design problems here. First of all, construct form `BaseClass const &` and `BaseClass &&` instead of `BaseClass*`. Also, I'd like to know why `BaseClass` even has any public constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the type of an object, so it's a bit hard to know what "upgrade an object" is intended to mean. But judging from the code, it's more or less "copy the data from the original object into a new one and get rid of the original object". That's easy:

```
class base {
public:
    base(int m) : mem1(m) {}
    base(const base&) = default;
private:
    int mem1;
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    derived(int m1, int m2) : base(m1), mem2(m2) {}
    derived(const base* b, int m2) : base(*b), mem2(m2) {}
private:
    int m2;
};

base* bp = new base(3);
base* temp = bp;
bp = new derived(temp, 4);
delete temp;
```

If that's too verbose you can write a function with a descriptive name:

```
void replace_object(base*& bp, int m2) {
    base* temp = bp;
    bp = new derived(temp, m2);
    delete temp;
}
```

and now you can write

```
base* bp = new base(3);
replace_object(bp, 4);
```

If you really, really want to hide all this stuff (maintainers will hate you), you can do the delete in the constructor for `derived`:

```
derived(const base* b, int m2) : base(*b), mem2(m2) {
    delete b;
}
```

and now you can write

```
base* bp = new base(3);
bp = new derived(bp, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response.

Comment: I really don't like the suggestion about deleting `b` from `derived` constructor. This is error prone. It one wants to transfert ownership, `std::unique_ptr` should be used.

Comment: @Phil1970 -- that's why I introduced that with "If you really, really want to hide all this stuff (maintainers will hate you)...".

Answer (score 0):

You code has a lot of issues.

I suggest you to read books on writing good code like **Exceptional C++** from **Sutter**.

**Issue 1:** Use the initialization list whenever appropriate.

```
BaseClass(int mem1, int mem2)
    : mem1(mem1)
    , mem2(mem2)
{
}

Inherited(int mem1, int mem2, int mem3)
    : BaseClass(mem1, mem2)
    , mem3(mem3)
{
}
```

> This would be more efficient for user defined types and required for
>   types that does not support assignation (constant and reference
>   members among others).
>
> Always initialize those members in declaration other.

**Issue 2:** Define standard copy constructor *(instead of your own variation)*

```
BaseClass(const BaseClass &other)
   : mem1(other.mem1)
   , mem2(other.mem2)
{
}
```

Even better. In this case, you can use default copy constructor.

```
BaseClass(const BaseClass &other) = default;
```

**Issue 3:** If you define the copy constructor, you should define the assignment operator too.

```
BaseClass& operator=(const BaseClass &other) = default;
```

> You could also define move constructor and assignment as necessary.

**Issue 4:** You should never call `free` on an object allocated with `new`.

**Issue 5:** I most case, you should avoid transferring ownership through a constructor.

This is error prone as this is not what user are expecting. This make the code harder to maintain and if you are not careful, this can be a source of memory leak if an exception is throw from the constructor.

```
Inherited(const BaseClass &b, int m3) 
    : BaseClass(b)
    , mem3(m3) 
{
}
```

**Issue 6:** If you really want to transfer ownership, then you should use `std::unique_ptr` to make it clear that you are transferring it.

```
Inherited(std::uniquer_ptr<BaseClass> b, int m3) 
    : BaseClass(*b)
    , mem3(m3) 
{
}
```

And at call site, something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> p = std::make_unique<BaseClass>(1, 2);
std::unique_ptr<Inherited> q = std::make_unique<Inherited>(std::move(p), 3);
// at this point, p is null since ownership has been moved
p = q;
```

> I think that with recent version of C++, you could do the replacement in place instead of using a temporary variable.

**Issue 7:** You should avoid explicit memory management as it is error prone.

See issue 6 for code.

Or as it this case allocating memory is useless. Code like that would be far more optimal:

```
Base b(1, 2);
Inherited i(b, 3);
// Use i (by reference) from that point…
```

If `b` is not need anymore afterward, you could also write something like:

```
Inherited i2(Base(1, 2), 3);
```

At which point, why not write:

```
Inherited i3(1, 2, 3);
```

**Issue 8:** There is no such things are upgrading object type. You are simply assigning a new value to a pointer which is based on the old object.

And actually replacing an object would cause object slicing in your case.